# PropertyChangedCallback not triggered when DependencyObject Class Member is Modified

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, dependencyobject

I created a `DependencyObject` with properties in it, I also have it inherit `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

But when it is implemented as a `DependencyProperty`, it does not trigger `PropertyChangedCallback` when I change a single property from the `DependencyObject` both in design and code.

This is the dependency object that I will use for my `CustomControl`.

```
public class Basemap : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string identifier;
    private string name;
    private string alias;
    private string url;

    private Map.DetailRange detailrange;
    private Map.Attribution attribution;

    public string Identifier
    {
        get => identifier;
        set
        {
            identifier = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Identifier");
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public string Alias
    {
        get => alias;
        set
        {
            alias = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Alias");
        }
    }

    public string URL
    {
        get => url;
        set
        {
            url = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("URL");
        }
    }

    public Map.DetailRange DetailRange
    {
        get => detailrange;
        set
        {
            detailrange = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DetailRange");
        }
    }

    public Map.Attribution Attribution
    {
        get => attribution;
        set
        {
            attribution = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Attribution");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

It has a `PropertyChangedEventHandler` and invoking it whenever the `OnPropertyChanged` is called, just like in this [GUIDE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

This it the `DependecyProperty` I implemented into the `CustomControl` that has a `PropertyChangedCallback`.

```
public static DependencyProperty BasemapProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Basemap", typeof(Basemap), typeof(Browser), new PropertyMetadata(null, BasemapChanged));
private static void BasemapChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Basemap Changed");
}
```

But the `PropertyChangedCallback` is not triggered when an individual property's value is changed, but it is triggered only when the whole `DependecyObject` is updated or inserted. Both in design and code

```
<Window.Resources>
    <mMAP:Basemap x:Key="OpenStreetMap" 
                      Identifier="OpenStreetMap.Standard"
                      Name="OpenStreetMap Standard" 
                      Alias="OpenStreetMap" 
                      URL="https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" 
                      DetailRange="0,0,18"
                      Attribution="© OpenStreetMap contributors, CC-BY-SA" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Can anyone suggest any fixes to this?

Thank you.

**Edit**: I assigned the `PropertyChanged` event from the `DependecyObject` to the control:

```
Basemap.PropertyChanged += Basemap_PropertyChanged;
```

so it can be triggered every time any member of the `DependecyObject` class. It may be sacrilegious to do it to WPF, but works for me.

PS: I needed it to be grouped, for it is a configuration for the `CustomControl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not binding to the Dependency Property you defined in the control, that is why the `PropertyChangedCallback` `BasemapChanged` is not triggered.

While it works on some cases, I try to avoid implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface on Controls and use only Dependency Properties instead when binding is required.

```
public static DependencyProperty AliasProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(Alias),
    typeof(string),
    typeof(Basemap),
    new PropertyMetadata(null, AliasPropertyChangedCallback));

public string Alias
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(Alias); }
    set { SetValue(Alias, value); }
}

private static void AliasPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"New Value of Alias: {e.NewValue}");
}
```

See: [Dependency properties overview (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/dependency-properties-overview)

Comment: Should it be implemented to the DependencyObject Class or is it directly on the CustomControl?

Comment: Directly on the Control. No need for an extra DependencyObject.

Comment: Is there any other way to at least group properties?

Comment: Not sure what you are up to, or what the end goal is. If you want to re-use certain values for properties in different controls, try to create Style Resources.
Maybe create another question for your grouping issue.

Comment: I needed it to be an Object because it is a configuration for the Control. Thank you @quarkonaut , you gave me an idea to implement on other Controls.

Comment: In that case, you could maybe use complex types (i.e. your configuration objects) as type of your dependency properties and apply the configuration of the control in the `PropertyChangedCallback`.